# How to get results by adding 2 columns in same psql table in python

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psql

I recently started learning about databases. Now I am testing my skills on a database backed application in python. I have created 2 tables in database something like this

```
CREATE TABLE players
(
    id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name   TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE matches 
(
    game  SERIAL,
    winner SERIAL REFERENCES players(id),
    loser SERIAL REFERENCES players(id)
);
```

I am tying to make a query to those to get results as playerid, name wins, matches in order something like (id, name, wins, matches) .

I am using this code to do that

```
SELECT id, name, count(matches.winner) as wins, 
 (count(matches.winner) + count(matches.loser)) as match 
  FROM players LEFT JOIN matches ON players.id = matches.winner 
  GROUP BY players.id ORDER BY wins
```

it seems it is not working please help me to solve this.

Thanks.

I have tried this code below

```
    DB = connect()
    c = DB.cursor()
    c.execute("""WITH
                   results AS (
                            select P.id,
                                   P.name,
                                   1     win
                            from   players P inner join matches M
                            on M.winner = P.id
                            union all
                            select P.id,
                                   P.name,
                                   0    win
                            from   players P inner join matches M
                            on M.loser = P.id)
                select id,
                       name,
                       sum(win)   wins,
                       count(*)   matches
                from   results
                group by id, name """)
    return c.fetchall()
    DB.close()
```

This code is not getting any data from the database instead it is returning just []. I have also tried to replacing my query string with

```
query = oldstring.replace(" ","_")
c.execute(query)
```

but it is also not worked. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you please show some sample data and what you are getting and what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you probably don't want to use `SERIAL` data type for FK columns, as it is an autoincrementing integer type which is good for PK, but not suitable for FK, better stick with `INTEGER`.

Second, consider some constraints to enforce what we call business-rules. Are there always two players? Is it realistic for match to have no winner or loser? What if it ends with a tie?

Anyway, let's keep it simple for now and assume that any time two players face each other one of them emerges the winner while the other one loses. So the total number of matches is wins + losses.

```
WITH
  results AS (
    select P.id,
           P.name,
           1     win
    from   players P inner join matches M
    on M.winner = P.id
    union all
    select P.id,
           P.name,
           0    win
    from   players P inner join matches M
    on M.loser = P.id)
select id,
       name,
       sum(win)   wins,
       count(*)   matches
from   results
group by id, name
```

So, what is going on here:

- `WITH` is a [Common Table Expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html). It is basically a named subquery. I used it here for readability. I could put subquery inside the `FROM` clause, but it looks much better this way.
- You need to join `players` and `matches` somehow, but each row in `matches` references two players. Ok, then, we will join them twice.
- When you join on `matches.winner` you get one row for every match, and there is the winner in this row. This is already enough to count wins, but there is absolutely no info on losses.
- Second query adds one more row for every game, but this time there is loser in this row.
- `UNION ALL` combines results of two queries in one resultset.
- But we need to be able to distinguish between rows with different outcomes. The simpliest way is to sum numbers, so I set `1` for wins and `0` for losses.
- Finally [group](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) rows now using `GROUP BY` and aggregate.

You can count losses in similar fashion.

Comment: Hi, i tried this but unfortunately this code is not able to retrieve any data from the table. when i try to print i am only getting [] instead of table. I am going to past my code in my question.

Comment: Provide some sample data, please. Without looking at it I don't see any reason for resultset to be empty.

Comment: Yes it is working... Thank you very much. Because i am beginner to databases can you please explain your code ?

Comment: I added little description to my post. Hope that helps.